# auto generate an employeeID using jsp, java servlet, and mysql (wamp server) in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, wampserver

Can someone please tell me how to auto generate an employeeID using jsp, java servlet, and mysql (wamp server) in eclipse. I tried all the codes but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements... There are many different ways to generate a unique ID.

You mention mysql, so you could create a table with an id field which auto increments and you could use this as your employeeID. This would be the easiest option. Whenever you insert a new employee to the employee table, return the id field.

Another way would be to just generate a UUID with the java.util.UUID class.

```
  UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
  String employeeID = uuid.toString();
```